# How to conditionally copy the data rows from one Excel Worksheet to another

Tags: excel, for-loop, copy, worksheet, vba

I have a list of projects and project details in my "Project Master" Excel Worksheet placed in 4 columns: project type, project numbers, project value, and project managers' names. I want to write a macro to copy the content of these 4 columns from the "Project Master" Worksheet to another Worksheet ("Details") in the same Workbook but only if the row contains the project type "A". Is this possible?
Regards,
CK

Comment: I guess, by Tab you actually mean  a Worksheet? Please clarify. Best regards,

Comment: Hi Alex, you are correct - sorry - I meant copying data between worksheets under certain conditions within the same workbook.

Comment: It's OK, I have edited the question and posted the answer. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pertinent to your task description, the sample `Worksheet` content may look like shown in the following table:

```
Type    Num Value   Manager Name
B       3   3.14    I. Newton
A       5   2.71    T. Edison
C       8   9.95    H. Ford
A       1   4.99    S. Jobs
D       4   21      G. Leibniz
```

and the corresponding sample VBA Sub `CopyDetails()` to perform the task is shown below:

```
Sub CopyDetails()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow As Long

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Master")
  LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To LastRow
    If (ws.Range("A" & i) = "A") Then
        ws.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Details").Range("A" & i)
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you may set the reference to Excel `Worksheet` objects like for e.g.:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the prompt and kind answer to my question - very useful, and is helping my project a lot. Regards, CK

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it works for you. Please mark the answer accepted if you are satisfied with the solution. Good luck with your project. Kind regards,